# Как запретить обтекание текстом?

Tags: html, html5, css

```
<div>
   <div class="photo">text</div>
</div>

.photo {
float:left
}
```

Если текст длинный - заходит под картинку

Comment: Т.е. у вас типа этого http://jsfiddle.net/73o6habL/ ?

Comment: Да - в точности.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yxjdenwo/ - а неообходимо так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lfm9pL7/

Посмотрите еще этот вариант.